# Prepend item in div and later on outside after clicks

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make some code and replace some button positions, because on desktop I use an inline position and on mobile I don't want to. That's why I put my button before the hidden text, but when I'm on mobile I want the button after the hidden text, so I use `prepend()` for that:

HTML:

```
<a class="btn active" data-target"#info-text" data-toggle="collapse">button</a>
  <div class="collapse info-text">
     <p>texttexttext</p>
     <b>{{I want it here after click one and after click two, to his original position}}</b>
  </div>
<b>{{Or here, I don't know what's easier}}</b>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
  var windowSize = $(window).width();
  if(windowSize <= 600 && $(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).next($(".hiddenText")).append($(this));
  }
  else if(windowSize <= 600 && !$(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).next($(".hiddenText")).prepend($(this));
  } 
})
```

The `append()` is working correctly (the button is below inside the div), but after the second click I want it outside the div. Otherwise it would collapse and the button is not visible anymore. Or is there a better way to replace the a tag position with the div position? There can be multiple messages, that's why I'm using the next property.

Comment: I edited your code... Have a look at [how to edit questions](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Ooh i',m sorry and thank you. I will do it better next time. This is the first time i'm using this for a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To revert the action of "moving" an element... You have to take its new DOM position in account to move it again.

So to revert a `.next().append()` is `.parent().before()`.

Also toggle the `active` class!

```js
$(".btn").click(function () {
  var windowSize = $(window).width();
  if(windowSize <= 600 && $(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).next(".info-text").append($(this).toggleClass("active"));
  }
  else if(windowSize <= 600 && !$(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).parent(".info-text").before($(this).toggleClass("active"));
  }
  
  // Just for this demo
  if(windowSize > 600){
    console.log("Resize the window to less than 600px to run me...")
  }
})
```

```css
#info-text{
  border: 1px solid red; /* Just for this demo */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a class="btn active" data-target="#info-text" data-toggle="collapse">button</a>
<div id="info-text" class="collapse info-text">
  <p>texttexttext</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Louys, thank you this is working. Maybe it was an stupid question, but I'm not familiar with the parent action. You make my day :)

Comment: Great! :) Can you mark tha answer as accepted? (the green check mark)